# Portable Java Installation

Tags: java, windows

I'm trying to make Java work with some commands in a .bat file without installation. I have the Java folder that is installed in C:\Program Files when you normally install Java and Init.bat which does this:

```
set JAVA_HOME="C:\Users\mega\Desktop\DISK\Apps\Java"
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Users\mega\Desktop\DISK\Apps\Java\bin
assoc .jar=jarfile
ftype jarfile="C:\Users\mega\Desktop\DISK\Apps\Java\bin\javaw.exe" "%1"
```

It should set the 2 environment variables and associating the variables, first of all, they don't set the variables, I do not know why but I am sure that I can fix it after this topic, but even then, I set them manually and when I try to open a .jar file it doesn't work.

So the Java is in 1 folder and it should function like if a Java were to be installed normally, but it doesn't, any help is good since I can't figure it out.

Comment: Setting environment variables via the command line will only apply to the current shell/cmd.exe/Powershell. So it won't change the system-wide values (which is what you see if you open the environment variables system dialog). Also `JAVA_HOME` might not be relevant, only a small handful of applications actually read this variable. Most either just look for `java.exe` on the path or ship their own JDK/JRE.

Comment: This is not Java question per se, when executing e.g Java Program with eclipse it looks for the Java environment. Now you can set manually, or this can come by default, with installation of Java installer. The installer is a pre-compiled binaries, and packaged into a single file. You can place the binaries in right place. But the catch is setting the environment settings, as @Joachim mentioned

Comment: That's helpful to know, but even if I put them manually, launching any .jar file won't work.

Comment: In eclipse set `java build path` to the jdk location. Currently I am using Java in windows, make sure - you check all environment variables, there should be no other `JAVA_HOME` present from previous setting, previous user - any other uses like Android Studio, so check the `Environment_Variables` and the eclipse build path, as the only two things to check for.

Comment: Uh, I think this is a mistake from me, I'm not installing Java to code, I'm installing it to use it for games that need it, I need to make it portable so that it doesn't need to be installed.

Comment: So, if you are using it for portable minecraft USB drive, just be sure in the PC, do they have previously installed JAVA reference from environment variables? This is the only thing to check for. So, my suggestion is - before adding the `PATH` check for pre-existing Java installations and Enviroment variables reference if any, and remove with bash scripting, and add them in the subsequent bash lines.

Comment: I'm using Shadow Defender to be more safe against viruses, and one thing against that is putting everything in a folder and everything outside that folder won't get changed. This leads me to putting Java in a folder called DISK, and in the Init.bat someone made the script for me but I deleted the original Init.bat file by accident so I'm trying to make it by myself. Yes, there is the Java folder and I have checked and there are no missing ones + I've also used "setX" to turn them into permanent environment variables and after that [...]

Comment: [...] I'm using this

assoc .jar=jarfile
ftype jarfile="C:\Users\mega\Desktop\DISK\Apps\Java\bin\javaw.exe" "%1"

Comment: And when I'm trying to launch Minecraft it simply tells me that I do not have java installed. (sorry for posting in 3 comments)
EDIT: An launcher for Minecraft does work because I got java in the environment variables and files, but I think some other launchers doesn't recognize it because it's missing something in the registry, such as a key.

Comment: So basically the last thing I have to do right now is tell Windows (in registry keys I believe) that Java is installed and where the file is so that apps can now see that I have it installed, but I don't have a clue about where that registry key's hiding.